# Custom RatingBar shows always five stars

Tags: android, android-styles, ratingbar

I'm developping an Android app, which use a custom RatingBar. I've follow a tutorial (http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/), but when I use my custom style, it always shows me 5 stars, even I force the RatingBar to a value (Ex 3 stars). I verified on the web with some others tutorials, but it doesn't change anything..

My files :

custom_ratingbar_full.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar_full_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

custom_ratingbar_full_empty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_off" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_off" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_off" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_off" />

</selector>
```

custom_ratingbar_full_filled.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_full" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_full" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_full" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_full" />

</selector>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_ratingbar_full</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">48dip</item>
</style>
```

my_fragment.xml

```
...

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
            style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

...
```

Any explanations ? I've search what I've done wrong, but I don't find it..

**EDIT :**

How I set my rating value :

I send a bundle between Fragments

```
myRating = bundle.getInt("rating");
```

I retrieve the RatingBar :

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rating_beer);
```

And finnaly I test the value to show or not the rating bar :

```
if (beerRating != 0) {
    ratingBar.setRating(myRating);
    ratingBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Rating : " + myRating, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I have verified my value, and it doesn't show me the correct number of stars. But if I remove my custom style from the rating bar, it works.

**EDIT 2 SOLUTION :**

Finally I found the solution : I have replaced tags `@+android:id` by `@+id`, and this is why it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the code where you assign rating to rating bar ?

Comment: @Azuken in tutorial You mentioned there were no "@+android:id" and I have the same problem, but can't find a way through. How did You done that?

Comment: In the tutorial, tags were written `@+android:id`, and my IDE showed this lika an error, so I replaced them. But you must write like it says in the tutorial to have your app working

Comment: I've done it like in tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208154/custom-ratingbar-showing-five-stars-despite-setrating

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. I downloaded the code and the items in the custom rating bar file were like this

```
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_blank"/>
```

to remove the error I changed the id to

```
 <item
 android:id="@+id/background"
 android:drawable="@drawable/star_blank"/>
```

which removed the error but it was only showing the selected items stars but the rating bar value was changing.

So I changed id in custom rating bar to

```
<item
android:id="@android:id/background"
android:drawable="@drawable/star_blank"/>
```

which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , Set the progress drawable as a property of rating bar,

```
                        <RatingBar

                        android:numStars="5"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar_selector"
                        android:stepSize="0.2" />
```

Comment: Finally I found the solution : I have replaced tags "@+android:id" by "@+id", and this is why it didn't work. Thank you anyway !